# how to set a dhcp clientid via netctl via dhcpcd

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp

I'm trying to set a string as dhcp clientid in a netctl profile.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
#DHCPClient=(dhcpcd 'clientid="string"')
#DHCPClient=(dhcpcd clientid string )
#DHCPClient=(dhcpcd 'clientid=string' )
#DHCPClient=(dhcpcd -I string)
DHCPClient=('dhcpcd -I string')
```

If I set the clientid in the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file like this `clientid string` instead of `duid`, it works like a charm but is active on all profiles that use dhcpcd. I want the clientid to be overwritten only this profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an workaround by duplicating the config and specifiying the additional argument `-f /etc/dhcpcd-diffrent-clientid.conf`.

```
IP=dhcp
DHCPClient=(dhcpcd)
DhcpcdOptions='-f /etc/dhcpcd-diffrent-clientid.conf'
```

Now some netctl profiles use the normal config file with the duid as identifier and some use my special clientid string.